# Determine when a style sheet has been been edited via Developer Tools (without extension)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, stylesheet, google-chrome-devtools

Are there any JavaScript events that are fired when a stylesheet is edited via the developer tools?

I have not been able to find any useful events off of `document.styleSheets[0]`.

This only needs to work with Chrome. 
This only needs to work for style sheets that are on the same domain as the html page and javascript code (so the `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` are available).

I know I could create a chrome extension, however I would really rather not if it's avoidable. (I've never created one before so it will take time, and it's just one more thing to install, update, etc.)

One option is to simply poll the `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` every few seconds to see if there are any changes, however this would waste a lot of CPU cycles and cause some other problems.

It seems like there must be a clean way to be notified when style sheet's are edited via the dev tools.

I know it's an unusual requirement, please trust that it is a valid requirement :)

Thanks,

Comment: Look at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but i'm not sure that it'll handle changes from developer tools.

Comment: What about changing the CSS values in any number of other ways like a user script, an extension or so on?

Comment: i don't think polling a single sheet will use much CPU, especially if it's only every few seconds to pluck the cssText from each rule. such a scan takes less than a ms, so 0.003% cpu is livable...

Comment: @dandavis, thanks for the insight. i might have to poll.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I'm not interested in css that changes via other methods.

Comment: @Givi, thanks, I'm looking in to MutationObserver now. So far, it looks like it just observes DOM mutations, not CSS changes like color. But I will keep playing with it.